# Mostrar array en tabla

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar una array en javascript en una tabla HTML?

```
<body>
<p id="cliente"></p>    
    <script>
        var client = ["10001500", "Benito", "sdfdsadasfl.com", "C/Falsa123"];
        document.getElementById("cliente").innerHTML = client;
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar una tabla HTML con JS, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```js
function crearTabla(datosTabla) {
  var tabla = document.createElement('table');
  var cuerpoTabla = document.createElement('tbody');

  datosTabla.forEach(function(datosFilas) {
    var fila = document.createElement('tr');

    datosFilas.forEach(function(datosCeldas) {
      var celda = document.createElement('td');
      celda.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datosCeldas));
      fila.appendChild(celda);
    });

    cuerpoTabla.appendChild(fila);
  });

  tabla.appendChild(cuerpoTabla);
  document.body.appendChild(tabla);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="crearTabla([['10001500', 'Benito', 'benito.com', 'C/Falsa123'], ['10047500', 'Dianita', 'dianita.com', 'C/Verdadera789']]);">Crear Tabla</button>
```